# How to obtain relative movement and rotation of bridge bearings?

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-analysis, modeling, bridges

In structural analysis of a bridge using whatever software, such as MIDAS or SAP 2000, it is easy to obtain the deformation of individual nodes. However, for bearings, what we want is the relative displacement of top and bottom nodes. As we have thousands of load cases, we envelope them into load combinations to get the maximum and minimum forces and deformations. How does one derive the bearing movements with ease?

Comment: I believe you mean that "for bearings, what we want is the relative displacement between the beam and column" (or any two structural elements at the same node), correct? Or are you analysing the pad with an equivalent beam?